# \textit is to \emph as \textbf is to...?

Tags: bold, italic, emphasis

Supposedly, `\emph` is more "semantic" while `\textit` can be seen as an aspect of its implementation. LaTeX has no `\strong` --- as opposed to, say, HTML which has both `<em>` and `<strong>`. So should I roll my own `\strong` or is it just overkill? Or is there some other, equivalent, command?

Comment: note that `\emph` is not just a different name for `\textit` it's behaviour is also different.

Comment: The idea is that emphasis should be realized the same across the document. I think no reader can really catch a nuance between “italic emphasis” and “boldface emphasis”.

Comment: I'm not aware of a second command for semantic emphasis. I also doubt that it is necessary. Sometimes "italics" or "bold" is just meant to be "italics" or "bold"; hiding it behind another name then doesn't help. On the other hand, a true emphasis command will take care of the context and choose an appropriate way for adding emphasis, like `\emph` does: in an upright text `\emph` will typeset in italics, but in an italics text it typesets upright.

Comment: The claim that "`\emph` is more 'semantic' while `\textit` is a way of implementing it" is incorrect.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Restated that.

Comment: @Mico -- in your answer you showed how the definition of `\emph` is depending on the definition of `\em` which makes use of `\itshape` which again relates to `\textit` in the exact same way as `\em` to `\emph`. Saying that the OP's claim is not correct isn't correct either. :) It's more a simplification and IMO it's not even that unsound.

Comment: @Ruben - Maybe I wasn't clear enough: The *default* method for `\em`'s "outer" emphasis is indeed `{\itshape ...}`. However, this setting isn't immutable: it can be changed by modifying one or more of the macros listed in my answer. Moreover, as I also point out in the answer,`\emph` allows for emphasis-within-emphasis using just one command, viz., `\emph`. One *could*, I suppose, diligently keep track of whether one is about to emphasize some material while in, italic mode and use `\textup{...}` for those cases. But why not keep life simple and use `\emph{... \emph{...} ...}`?

Comment: @Ruben - Also, I wrote my comment *before* the OP edit his posting and rephrased his take on what `\textit` does. The modified claim is definitely less strong (pun intended). Should I delete my earlier comment since it applies to a claim that's been modified subsequently?

Comment: @Mico, you were clear. And in the meantime I suspected that the edits to the OP were of this kind. Don't delete your comment. I think like this everything important has been said and clarified.

Comment: You might look at the `\alert` command from `beamer` as another 'semantic' command. (I wouldn't use it in most non-beamer documents, however.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The idea behind `\emph` is that it provides a high level way for giving emphasis to a part of the text. High level in the sense it is “independent” of the actual implementation.

The default behavior of `\emph` is to use italics when in an upright context and upright when in an italics context, but this can be modified on a document’s basis (or by a package implementing a particular style). In particular, your question has no real answer: `\emph` and `\textit` bear no “abstract” relationship; the relationship is only at the default implementation level.

This is different from stating some part of text is in italics; for instance, theorems are commonly typeset in italics and the styles use `\itshape` for this, not `\em` (the declarative form of `\emph`). Similarly they use `\bfseries` for the theorem tag (or `\scshape` or whatever).

You're free to define as many similar commands as you want. If your style requires a sort of “strong emphasis”, you *can* define `\strong` as you please, maybe using `\bfseries` in normal context and `\extrabfseries` (if your font supports it, the name is hypothetical) in a `\strong` context. Before doing this, think deeply whether your readers will be able to appreciate the difference between `\emph{word}` and `\strong{word}` (which I think they won't).

Answer (score 10):

There may be some confusion as to how `\emph` and `\em` are defined. From the latex kernel (cf `latex.ltx`):

```
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\emph}{\em}
\DeclareRobustCommand\em
        {\@nomath\em \ifdim \fontdimen\@ne\font >\z@
                       \eminnershape \else \itshape \fi}%
\def\eminnershape{\upshape}%
```

Basically, `\emph` (via `\em`) checks if it's already in "emphasis mode". If it's not, `\itshape` is executed; and if it is, `\eminnnershape` -- which, by default, is set to `\upshape` -- is executed. (`\eminnershape` can be modified via a `\renewcommand` instruction. E.g., running `\renewcommand\eminnershape{\scshape}}` would select small-caps for "inner" emphasized material.)

So it's not the case that `\emph` is just "more semantic" than `\textit`. Indeed, `\emph` *is* more semantic -- it lets you choose the method of typographic emphasis (the defaults are `\itshape` for "outer" and `\upshape` for "inner" material) -- but it also provides a way of providing emphasis *within emphasized material.*

Finally, just in case you're curious how `\DeclareTextFontCommand` is defined in the LaTeX kernel, here goes:

```
\def \DeclareTextFontCommand #1#2{%
  \DeclareRobustCommand#1[1]{%
    \ifmmode
      \nfss@text{#2##1}%
    \else
      \hmode@bgroup
       \text@command{##1}%
       #2\check@icl ##1\check@icr
       \expandafter
      \egroup
    \fi
                       }%
}
```